# Instruction Execution

Tags: assembly, verilog, cpu-architecture

I am reading a book about introduction to Computer Architecture.
There are some text passage which reads: "RISC instructions typically take one clock cycle". Then it shows the follow Verilog snippet as illustration:

```
always @(positiveclockedge clk )

begin

case ( state )
    STATE_FETCH:
        begin
          fetch;
          state = STATE_DECODE;
        end
    STATE_DECODE:
        begin
            decode;
            state = STATE_EXECUTE;
        end
    STATE_EXCUTE:
        begin
            execute;
            state = STATE_FETCH;
        end
endcase
end
```

According to the Verilog snippet, each instruction takes at least 3 clock cycles (ignoring any memory access delay), even a RISC processor. So there is a seeming contradiction. Can someone help to fix it?

Comment: Google "processor pipeline".

Comment: The text presumably means "typically take one clock cycle [to execute]" (i.e., only one "execute" pipeline stage). Single-cycle execution simplifies design of an efficient pipeline since dependent instructions can execute consecutively. The original Microprocessor *without* Interlocked Pipeline Stages even used a load delay slot to allow load instructions to be treated as single-cycle execute (forcing the compiler to avoid placing a dependent instruction immediately after a load instruction).

Comment: I think that comment is my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Something like a "delay slot" should act also on fetch stage because there is needed memory access. Correct?

Comment: The structural hazard of instruction fetch and data access potentially both wanting to be done at the same time would generally be handled by stalling. Many processors use separate instruction and data caches to reduce the frequency of this hazard (in addition to the other benefits); since a cache miss in a very simple design would require a stall anyway, this allows some simplification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can also google "risc architecture". or
2. refer to the wikipedia page on RISC DLX architecture. or
3. refer to book by hennesey and patterson, which discusses in detail the risc architecture.

normally you have a pipelined risc architecture (fetch - decode - execute - write back). instruction are executed in single cycle. but the entire pipeline may take more cycles, depending the architecture you are following to implement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful. tanks.
The subject  is simply to get a holistic view about how better programing (i.e.,assembly). I dont want to delve in the processor design matter.